# Order of Index Update in Sitecore

Tags: solr, indexing

What will be the order of solr indexes getting updated after create/update item in Sitecore CM or CD.

What should i do if i need to changes the order of index update.

e.g i need build the custom indexes before updating Sitecore out of the box indexes on item save/create.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to understand Sitecore Index Update strategies and define the strategy for your own custom index and sitecore will take care of updating indexes. Read here:- https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/index-update-strategies.html

Comment: This is not about the indexing strategies.All the indexes which doesn;t need to be updated on create update are already set to manual

Comment: Why would you need the custom indexes updated first? There is no guaranteed order for the out-of-the-box update strategies. It would theoretically be possible to create a custom update strategy that was shared between several indexes and imposed some order, but I can't think of a good reason why you would want to do that.

Comment: @BenGolden: That was give as an example. One of the custom index is failing  and apparently other indexes are also affected. So me want to make sure the problematic index updates should not affect the other index updates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to change the order of the index update, the index rebuild is happening on the same order as in sitecore/contentSearch/configuration/configuration in showconfig.

First I saved an items and checked the order of order of index update from logs.

Then I updated the order of the the indexes, checked showconfig verified the order is updated. Then i saved an item and checked the order of indexes updated in logs and it was aligned to the same order is as in showconfig

Answer (score 0):

The out-of-the-box update strategies do not guarantee any particular order order. While it may be possible to create a custom update strategy that imposed some order to the index updates, I do not think that it would be a good idea. You do not want to introduce a dependency from one index on another.

If you feel that you need to change the order of index updates, I would recommend that you reexamine the situation. It would be far better to address the cause of the failure than to introduce a hack to work around it.